# Editing a deleted question or should I ask a new question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

One of my previous questions was voted to be deleted. It needs one vote to undelete. That question had two answers with more than 10 upvotes, but the question was not well-received (six downvotes). In order to respect the efforts of those who answered, I decided to keep it even after six down-votes.

Now I want to edit that question, but there is no option to edit a deleted question. Should I ask a new question?

**Why do I want to edit a deleted question?**

1. There was no reason mentioned for deleting. Only reason I can think of is duplicate. With my explanation I'm sure it will not look like a duplicate.
2. It was a feature request, but it was deleted without understanding my request properly. My request is entirely different from the previous ones in duplicate.
3. I feel guilty about upvoted answers. Somehow I feel my question is responsible for discarding their efforts.

Comment: If you edited it, would your edits invalidate any of the existing answers?

Comment: @Robert It will not invalidate existing answers. But they might need to improve their answer for accepting